# lapply function with RSelenium

Tags: r, rselenium

My Session is something like this:

```
startServer()
remDir <- remoteDriver()
remDir$open()
Source <- paste0("https://www.example.com")
remDir$navigate(Source)
```

I am parsing some link:

```
HTML   <- remDir$getPageSource()
tmp    <- xpathSApply(htmlParse(HTML[[1]]),
                          ' //a/@href')
```

And now I want to parse each tmp link:

```
srcPartOne <- paste0(Source, as.list(tmp)[185:199],"/")
HTMLs      <- lapply(srcPartOne, getURL)
```

But in this point, getURL function not usage for me. Because links contains dynamic page. So, I need use RSelenium in the `lapply` function like something like this:

```
HTMLs      <- lapply(srcPartOne, remDir$navigate,remDir$pageSource)
```

I gave an example, I know that doesn't work. How Can I parse each link using RSelenium?
edit :

```
library(RSelenium)
  library(RCurl)
  library(rdrop2)
  library(pbapply)

  #Start RSelenium
  drop_auth()  #Dropbox Authentication
startServer()
remDir <- remoteDriver()
remDir$open(silent = TRUE)

#Set 'Vitrin' sources to get mobil number:
Source <- paste0("https://www.sah1b1nden.com")
remDir$navigate(Source)
HTML   <- remDir$getPageSource()
tmp    <- xpathSApply(htmlParse(HTML[[1]]),
                          ' //a/@href')



#Get HTML framework from each ' Vitrin' sources:
#

srcPartOne <- paste0(Source, as.list(tmp)[185:232],"/")
pblapply(srcPartOne, function(x) {
  remDir$navigate(x)
  remDir$getPageSource()
}) -> pgs

Parses<- lapply(X = pgs[1:48], htmlParse) 

temp       <- lapply(Parses, xpathSApply, '//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "show-part", " " ))]',xmlValue)
```

Comment: can't even show `srcPartOne`? it wld help to know if they're relative or full URIs

Comment: I suspected the lack of URL was due to this being an attempt at Terms of Service violation. It is (specifically section 4:11).

Comment: I can parse one by one section 4:11 . For Example fourh section: `src1 <- paste0(Source, as.list(tmp)[[200]])` 
`pageSource1 <- remDir$getPageSource()
 number1 <- xpathSApply(htmlParse(pageSource1[[1]]),                                          
                  '//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "show-part", " " ))]', xmlValue)
person1 <- xpathSApply(htmlParse(pageSource1[[1]]),                                          
                       '//h5', xmlValue)`